# Structural Diagrams for C

Tags: c, diagram

I am trying to read and understand the source of an existing C project. I keep feeling like it would be great to draw a UML Class Diagram for it to help me understand the high level relationships better, but of course - there are no classes to model.

Is there a formal diagram system that is used to model module relationships in a non-OO language? One that would be on a similar level of abstraction to a UML Class Diagram.

Comment: you could look at the call graph

Comment: why can't you use UML exactly? You could have the modules as boxes with the functions/methods as elements of that with seperate boxes describing them or something, no?

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) to map your function tree.

Answer (score 2):

The OO paradigm is not a property of programming language and it's very possible to make OO implementation in C (just hard and not very intuitive). The OO design (in UML or any other modeling language) is not bound to a specific language.

Now let's get back to your question. There are many tools available for non-OO design. You can find a nice summary [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modeling_language) and choose what fits you best.

Answer (score 1):

Try FMC ( http://www.fmc-modeling.org/home) and "Apache Modelling Project" (Apache HTTP Sever modeled using FMC: http://www.fmc-modeling.org/projects/apache) as a starting point and guideline.